# printf() not working with wchar_t no matter what I try

Tags: c, wchar-t, wchar

This doesn't work - nothing is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t a = 0xfe;
    printf("%lc",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I've just been staring at it and trying different things for minutes.

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t a = '\u00FE';
    printf("%lc",a);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t a = '\U000000FE';
    printf("%lc",a);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t a = 0xfe;
    wchar_t* b = &a;
    printf("%ls",b);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t* b = L"\u00FE";
    printf("%ls",b);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t a = 0xfe;
    printf("%C",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing works. The only thing that works is this, but say I want it in a variable:

```
printf("\u00FE");
```

Actually, the tooltip in vscode does show a thorn, but the actual program doesn't.

Environment: Windows 10, VSCode, just the C/C++ Extension Pack, GCC GNU something MinGW (I think)

Comment: Which terminal are you using and does it support unicode & utf-8?

Comment: 0x00fe is the Unicode code point. Encoded as UTF-8 it would be: 0xc3, 0xbe.

Comment: Try `wint_t a = 0xfe;  printf("%lc",a);`.

Comment: @stark Using 2 variables worked: `wchar_t a = 0xc3; wchar_t b = 0xbe; printf("%lc%lc",a,b);` but is there a way to make it into 1 var?

Comment: @Bfyuvf You can write `wchar_t a = L'þ'` or `wchar_t a = L'\u00FE'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal you are printing to expects a stream of bytes which encode the characters that you wish to print.  Here's how you could encode your character and print it to a terminal which understands UTF-8:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(void) {
    char a[] = { 0xc3, 0xbe, '\n', 0};
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
þ
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you (forgot I could put it in an array)